# Show dots in a span when the browser window size changes based on pure css

Tags: html, css

I want to display text inside a span element in maximum two rows.

E.g. The full size of the browser window:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

E.g. when the browser window width changes to smaller:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text 
of the printing and typesetting…
```

If it takes more than two rows to display the text I want to show three dots to the client. 
I tried to find some solution based on pure CSS. I’ve tried use

```
.truncate {
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow:hidden !important;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

but it doesn’t work for the dynamic size changes of the browser window. I had also an idea to replace the span with textarea but it also didn't work in my case. I believed that this must be something trivial but after hours of research, I cannot find any meaningful solution on the web. Please keep in mind that 'span' element is a sub element of the sidebar section. If I make some changes to it, I don't want it to have an impact on changing properties such size of other elements.
Is there any option to achieve what I want without using any javascript libraries?

Comment: As far as pure CSS goes, I think you have a fundamental conflict here. `text-overflow: ellipsis` only works when word wrap is disabled (as you've done with `white-space: nowrap`, but you still want a little bit of word wrap -- up to a maximum of two lines. Word wrap is an all-or-nothing proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created my own implementation    https://codepen.io/mpiwowarski/pen/qybrqY:
The sample html code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
  <div class="ellipsis">
  <span>
  Call me Ishmael.  Some years ago &ndash; never mind how long precisely &ndash; having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world.  It is a way I have of driving off the spleen, and regulating the circulation.  
   </span>
  <div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:70%">
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

The css:

```
.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 25px;
     }
.ellipsis:before {
    content: "";
    float: left;
    width: 5px; 
  height: 50px; 
     }
.ellipsis > *:first-child {
    float: right;
    width: 100%; 
    margin-left: -5px;
    background: #AFF; }
.ellipsis:after {
    content: "...";
    float: right;
  position: relative;
    top: -25px;
  left: 100%;
    width: 100px; 
  margin-left: -100px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    background: white; 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
span::after {
       content: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
       typesetting industry blah blah blah...";
       }

@media screen and (max-width:600px){
      span::after {
      content: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text";
      }
    }
```

make sure you set your break point!

https://codepen.io/robbiemcmullen/pen/ajddGK

Comment: then <span><span> in your html